# How should I include an image field from a taxonomy term in a node view?

Tags: views, media

I'm creating a site with just one content type sorted in three categories and posted by three different organizations (no matter in which of the categories). The front page has to be three columns displaying the content of each category.

The nodes has to be distinguished by the logo of the organization. I'm trying to solve it by managing the organization as a taxonomy and creating an image field for each organization/term; when I deal with the view, I find that I just can use as field the name of the taxonomy and not the image (creating a view of node type of course).

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drupal 7 then you will have to add a **"Content: Taxonomy terms on node"** relationship before attempting to add the term image field. When you add the relationship then in the Fields section you will be able to choose term fields (like the image field of your terms) to display them in your content view.